# Python kivy shows only last label which generated in loop

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

last day i came across on very irritate behave my program. 
Mabye at first i show screenshot, describe error, and finnaly shows code.
[image]

As you can see, Coin is a button which contains a few sub-buttons. I generate these widgets in loop and dynamically add to layer.
But it works correctly only in last iterating.
Please look now at code.
Here is a code "Coin Button: class.
Note this, that for example: button apx, Refresh, H, DH and D is a member of one class

```
class SubButtonRefreshCoinData(Button):
    def __init__(self, coin_name, **kwargs):
        super(SubButtonRefreshCoinData, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.CoinName = coin_name
        self.text = "Refresh"
    def on_press(self):
        PopupNotImplementedItem().open()

class SubButtonCoinName(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SubButtonCoinName, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text = r'[color=ff3333]{}[/color]'.format(kwargs["text"])
        self.markup = True
        self.font_size='20sp'

class SubButtonGoToCoinHistory(Button):
    def __init__(self, coin_name, **kwargs):
        super(SubButtonGoToCoinHistory, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.CoinName = coin_name
        self.text = "H"
    def on_press(self):
        subprocess.Popen(f'py HistoryWindow.py {self.CoinName}', shell=True)

class SubButtonDeleteCoin(Button):
    def __init__(self, coin_name, **kwargs):
        super(SubButtonDeleteCoin, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.CoinName = coin_name
        self.text = "D"
    def on_press(self):
        PopupNotImplementedItem().open()

class SubButtonDeleteCoinHistory(Button):
    def __init__(self, coin_name, **kwargs):
        super(SubButtonDeleteCoinHistory, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.CoinName = coin_name
        self.text = "DH"
        print("sdfecvsdcdfwreafsq3456tedcqr4536wtger34r5cedwt4g5aced   erf34")
    def on_press(self):
        PopupNotImplementedItem().open()
```

Now, please take a look on the Builder class these pieces:

```
class CoinButton(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, coin_name, **kwargs):
        super(CoinButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.CoinName = coin_name
        topHalfLayout = BoxLayout(pos_hint={"top":1}, size_hint = [1,0.49], orientation = "horizontal")
        topHalfLayout.add_widget(SubButtonCoinName(text=str(self.CoinName)))
        topHalfLayout.add_widget(SubButtonRefreshCoinData(self.CoinName))
        self.add_widget(topHalfLayout)

        downHalfLayout = BoxLayout(pos_hint={"down":1}, size_hint = [1,0.49], orientation = "horizontal")
        downHalfLayout.add_widget(SubButtonGoToCoinHistory(self.CoinName))
        downHalfLayout.add_widget(SubButtonDeleteCoinHistory(self.CoinName))
        downHalfLayout.add_widget(SubButtonDeleteCoin(self.CoinName))
        self.add_widget(downHalfLayout)
```

As you can see, everything seems be correct, but only ONE picece of class is visible.
In class SubButtonDeleteCoinHistory i tired primitive debug this problem to see did this code is already run. As i saw in console, text was printed 3 times, that is correct value.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what is happening here, but I take a shot. I believe that every time a CoinButton is initialized, the bottom button were added with respect to the FloatLayout which and using the pos_hint: down push the button off the kivy app window. But for the life of me, when changing the down value to various ints and floats, there was no change. The best approach was to use pos_hint 'y' since we know that the height of the button is 0.49 the top can start at 0.5 upto 0.99 and the bottom can start at 0 upto 0.49.

```
topHalfLayout = BoxLayout(pos_hint={"y":0.5},size_hint = [1,0.49], orientation = "horizontal")
......
downHalfLayout = BoxLayout(pos_hint={"y":0},size_hint = [1,0.49], orientation = "horizontal")
```

Another better approach that I used was to create another BoxLayout which holds the top and bottom layouts, allowing the FloatLayout to add the widget as one thing. It provides better spacing in my opinion. 'outside[ [top/bottom] ]outside'

```
outside = BoxLayout(pos_hint={"top":1},size_hint = [1,2*0.49], orientation = "vertical")
......
topHalfLayout = BoxLayout(size_hint = [1,0.49], orientation = "horizontal")
......
outside.add_widget(topHalfLayout)
......
downHalfLayout = BoxLayout(size_hint = [1,0.49], orientation = "horizontal")
......
outside.add_widget(downHalfLayout)
self.add_widget(outside)
```